# The fastest way to paste copied Excel cells with paste option `value & keep original format`

Tags: microsoft-excel, paste

When copying cells, I often need to keep value & formation of the cell but NOT the original formulas.

Copying large range of cells, I couldn't see the `paste icon` to choose the associative options. Even though having the icon showed up, it's also a tiring steps.

Would love to have the fastest way possible. Please help.

Comment: Let us know if you want code to do this, VBA or C#. `Range.Value2 = object[,]` is the fastest unless you write directly to the file, eg Excel XML files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the old keyboard shortcuts, work great for me (I use the values option constantly).

Paste-special 'values'
`ALT` + `E` , `S` , `V`

Paste-special 'formats
`ALT` + `E` , `V` , `T`

Alternatively, I believe there is an option to change the default paste option in Office 2010 (not sure about earlier versions) or you could just record a macro to do this and then set a keybinding.

Comment: In office 2010 you can just (1) Paste - (2) press CTRL - (3) then the shortcut for the mode you need ("V" for "values only").